# Fetch single row if two columns in table have same values either ways

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns caller and callee with following values say

```
caller callee
999 888
888 999
999 555
555 333
555 999
```

now i want only single row in returned as

```
caller1    caller2  count 
999        888      2
999        555      1
555        333      1
555        999      2
```

Comment: Do you want to count the number of times each pair shows up in either direction?

Comment: Can you please post your sql query you have so far?

Comment: Hi gidil, yes i wanna how many these two calls to each other in either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN caller < callee THEN callee
         ELSE caller
       END      AS caller1,
       CASE
         WHEN caller < callee THEN caller
         ELSE callee
       END      AS caller2,
       Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN caller < callee THEN callee
            ELSE caller
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN caller < callee THEN caller
            ELSE callee
          END
```

Comment: you don't need to compare caller1 and caller2, just count them

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev - This does one scan of the table as opposed to two with the UNION.

Comment: Hello Martin Smith, thanks for perfect answer. If i need to make this one in LINQ could you please help me out making this query on LINQ

Comment: @RajeevKumar - Sorry I'm not that fluent with LINQ. Might be worth asking another question.